# Breadcrumbs Not Displaying in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

I do not see this on Stackoverflow, but may have missed it.

The path displays:

- on the home page always (i.e. whenever I go back to it)
- on any page where I start (e.g. displaying About box using File\View in Browser. It will show up once on the page I start the debug session until I go away and come back)

Here is the SiteMapPath master page insertion (in the header):

```
    <header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">Imagine Videos</p>
            <span class="breadcrumb">
                <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
                </asp:SiteMapPath>
            </span>
        </div>
```

...

Here is the site map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home" >
    <siteMapNode url="About.aspx" title="About"  description="About Imagine Videos" >
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="CatalogSearch/CatalogSearch.aspx" title="Catalog Search"
                 description="Catalog Search" />
    <siteMapNode url="Contact.aspx" title="Contact"
                 description="Contact Page" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Ideas appreciated. This seemed pretty simple. This is a ASP.NET Web Forms Application.

Thanks,
Buck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed the ".aspx" for the links on the master page. Doing this, the breadcrumbs displayed and behaved correctly. The code for the links behaved correctly otherwise without the .aspx. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

I would try applying the "breadcrumb" CSS class directly in the asp:SitePathMap control. I've found that the use of span tags around ASP.NET Web Forms controls to style them can, once in a blue moon, cause display issues.

```
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" CssClass="breadcrumb">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Comment: James - I like your solution, but that did not solve it unfortunately. The behavior is the same as described. Any other ideas? This is strange. Thanks!

Comment: Buck - I couldn't replicate in Firefox or IE. Perhaps IIS is misinterpreting the separate closure bracket for About. Could you try this in your web.sitemap:

  <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home" description="Home" >
    <siteMapNode url="About.aspx" title="About" description="About Imagine Videos" />
    <siteMapNode url="CatalogSearch/CatalogSearch.aspx" title="Catalog Search" description="Catalog Search" />
    <siteMapNode url="Contact.aspx" title="Contact" description="Contact Page" />
    </siteMapNode>

If that doesn't work, maybe you could you share more code?

Comment: James - Sorry for the delay. I will get back to you later today. The weekend and all. Thanks!

Comment: James - I tried your solution and no go unfortunately. I put the files on dropbox and now just need to figure out how to get the info you need to access them (probably not best to send login/password through these comments). Contact is alanro!rr1 a!t gmail d!ot com (no exclamations). I can send you whatever you need. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: James, did you get my email?